# Laravel 5.5 - ReflectionException (-1) Class does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I am trying to use ReflectionClass to get file name(from app directory) from a controller. For testing whether I can use the ReflectionClass or not i was trying in following way:

In my MyController.php

```
public function readContent()
{

    $files = app_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. "Drama.php"; 
    // It returns "F:\xampp\htdocs\projectDirectory\app\Drama.php"

    $class = new ReflectionClass($files);
    echo "file name:: ". $class->getFileName();
}
```

I have a `Drama.php` file in this path. But when I am running the route for this method, I get following error

```
ReflectionException (-1)
Class F:\xampp\htdocs\projectDirectory\app\Drama.php does not exist
```

I have updated my `composer.json` file like following:

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app",
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
```

So that, i can read my `app` directory files.

I also ran the following commands

- composer dump-autoload
- composer update
- php artisan config:clear
- php artisan cache:clear

But i am still getting this error. Can anyone tell me how can i resolve this ?

Comment: ReflectionClass takes the class path not file path. https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.construct.php try `new ReflectionClass('\App\Drama')` instead.

Comment: `new ReflectionClass('\App\Drama')` does not work. But `new ReflectionClass('\App')`. But it indicates `Illuminate\Support\Facades\App` directory. Not the `app` directory where models, controllers etc. are located. How can i read file of `app` directory ? @Bryan

Comment: You probably have a namespace issue with your Drama.php file. That's why it's not working. the start of the file should be `<?php namespace App;`

Comment: Yes, there was a namespace issue. Thanks :) @Bryan

Comment: You're welcome. Added my comment as an answer. Feel free to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here is `ReflectionClass` takes the class path as the [constructor argument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.construct.php), not file path. try `new ReflectionClass('\App\Drama')` instead.